# How to diplay md-grid-tile in first column?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have `md-grid` that builds table:

```
<div *ngFor="let replacement of getReplcaementRows()">
   <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="1" class="md-grid-body"></md-grid-tile>
</div>
```

So, how to change content only for cells in first column by vertically?

I mean this:

```
**1** 2 3 
**4** 5 6
**6** 7 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` from `*ngFor` to find out the first item in each row and add some `*ngIf` statements to control the view.

Example (using your example):

```
<md-grid-list rowspan="5" colspan="1" cols="3">
   <md-grid-tile  class="md-grid-body" 
                  *ngFor="let replacement of getReplcaementRows(); let i = index">
     <span *ngIf="i%3 == 0">**{{replacement}}**</span>
     <span *ngIf="i%3 != 0">{{replacement}}</span>
   </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LpFePGuGVkRQVuYT5yUm?p=preview)

[image: First column content modification demo]

Comment: Okay, but when I have an object model as: `{header: {}, left:{}, data:{}}` How can I reproduce this in grid?

Comment: Then you should add your object model details and and the array getting returned by `getReplcaementRows()` function in your question, so people know about it when they are answering. Looking at your comment, I have no clue what you mean!!!! Are you trying to display the whole object?? Is `getReplcaementRows()` returning a bunch of objects that look like `{header: {}, left:{}, data:{}}` ??